# Debugging queries inside stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, debugging, stored-procedures

Consider this stored procedure. The actual content of procedure doesn't matter, I am using it only for the sake of the example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[temp]
      @value1 varchar(50),
      @value2 varchar(50),
      @value3 varchar(50)
as      
begin
    Select *
    From valuesTable (nolock)
          inner join valuesTable2 RL (nolock)
                on (ValuesTable.ID = RL.RuleId and RL.Type = 'Something')     
    where @value1 = ValuesTable.RuleVal02
    and cast(@value2 as float) > cast(ValuesTable.RuleVal03 as float) and cast(@value2 as float) < cast(ValuesTable.RuleVal04 as float)
    --and (@value3 = ValuesTable.RuleVal05)
    and (@value3 = ValuesTable.RuleVal05 or ValuesTable.RuleVal05 = -1)
end
```

Now imagine that this (not very complex function) isn't working. I already know how to debug it both from Visual Studio and from SQL Server Management Studio, however, both cases are lacking:

The main failing point of this function is the big query that it executes. What I'd like to do then, is to take this query, copy it to a new query window and start executing it and debug it by modifying its various parts.

The basic way to debug that query would be copy it to a new query window, get the parameters from the executing code and then manually replace all the `@variables` with their actual value. That works, but it seems like a very unnecessary work to me and ideally I'd like to get the query, as it is executed on the server - With literal values instead of the parameters, e.g:

```
where 'actualValue' = ValuesTable.RuleVal02
and cast(4.2 as float) > cast(ValuesTable.RuleVal03 as float) and cast(4.2 as float) < cast(ValuesTable.RuleVal04 as float)...
```

Since it sounded like something I can only achieve from a profiler, I launched it. Then I configured the events to capture `SP:StmtStarting` event, to see the statements executed from stored procedures. To my surprise, however, the statements that I see in the profiler, still show with their parameter and not the actual literal value.

Is a way I could easily copy the actual query that is executed in a stored procedure with the parameters replaced to the literal value of the parameter? Is there a flag in the profiler to do so? Or is there another way?

Comment: But why do you need to *replace* the parameters with actual values? Why don't you just turn the parameter declaration part into a `DECLARE` statement, add the necessary set of assignments and run the script like that?

Comment: Well, it is really about the effort involved. If I have a complex C++ code that runs a SP that executes a query, then I first need to initiate SP debugging to get the values passed to the SP, then write a new query with DECLARES and initiate the values by some copy pasting, and only then I will get the result of the query.

It seems like a lot of work for something that should be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple workflow (requires 5 seconds):

1. Run SSMS.
2. Find your stored procedure in Object Explorer window.
3. Right click on it to display context menu and select 'Execute Stored Procedure...' from it.
4. Set ALL parameters values in the form displayed.
5. SSMS generates the script for you in new query tab (see script at the end of this answer).
6. Save this script for further use.
7. Run Debug -> Start Debugging this script and then Step Into EXEC statement.
8. Change parameter values and run next debug.

```t-sql
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[temp]
        @value1 = N'1',
        @value2 = N'2',
        @value3 = N'3'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

you could write your query in a variable, with placeholders instead of actual values, replace the placeholders at runtime and execute it with sp_executesql

obviously it's just a thing you should do for debug purposes and not in production ;)

here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8c43/5

there you have your query filled with actual content, inside the variable

Comment: That's an interesting idea... However, I really wouldn't like to turn ALL the queries in my SP to dynamic, there are just too many negative aspects involved: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: that's why i said "only for debug purposes" ;)